# How to hide my javascript but let other download my webpage with thr script without them knowing?

Tags: javascript, php, hyperlink, click

So this is how it goes... I wanted to create a javascript that redirects links to my URL. So if anyone copies my webpage, they try changing my links, when they upload it to their server, her links will still redirect to my links. Is this possible with js? Or if I use PHP to hide the location of my js. I want that js to still work in the webpage they copied and use. Like a sticky clickjacker. That's hard to find and remove. Or if possible they cant at all.

Comment: There's no way to 'hide the location of my js'. There's no way to stop them from removing anything you put in the html.

Comment: Everything that is in your browser is already downloaded to your PC/device before you even see it.  What you are asking for is not possible.  Why do you want to do this, because there may be a better solution for your actual problem?

Answer (score 7):

> I wanted to create a javascript that redirects links to my url.

This means that the user would have to already be at your URL because the JavaScript to redirect to your URL can only be added to pages that you control.

> So if anyone copies my webpage, they try changing my links, when they
>   upload it to their server, her links will still redirect to my links.

As soon as they make a copy of your code, it's *their* code and they can upload it anywhere they want without your knowledge. And, if they can change your links, they can also just remove any JavaScript you may have had in the file.

**What you want to do is not possible.**